# How can I crawl the internal links of a page with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

On the page below, I have 3 lists of links belonging to victims, malware and threat_source, and I want to enter their links and crawl their contents when I reach the above items during the crawl of this page.

https://icsstrive.com/incident/lockbit-ransomware-attack-significantly-impacts-owens-group-operations/

I wrote the following code for this and tried different things. The problem is that when it crawls the victim and goes to the others, it repeats the victim again in the output file and creates many duplicates and sometimes skip the malware or threat source.

```
# importing the scrapy module
import random
import scrapy
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from pycti import OpenCTIApiClient
import stix2
from pycti import (
    Identity,
    ThreatActor,
    Malware,
    Location,
    StixCoreRelationship,
    Report,
)
import json

class icsstriveSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    stix_objects=[]

    name = "icsstrive"
    start_urls = ['https://icsstrive.com/']
    baseUrl="https://icsstrive.com"
    pages = None

    def parse(self, response, **kwargs):
        links = response.css('div.search-r-title a::attr(href)').getall()
        for i in range(len(links)):
            links[i] = links[i]
        yield from response.follow_all(links, self.parse_icsstrive)
      
        if self.pages is None:
            self.pages=response.xpath('//a[@class="wpv-filter-pagination-link js-wpv-pagination-link page-link"]/@href').getall()
        if len(self.pages) >0:
            url=self.pages[0]
            self.pages.remove(url)
            yield response.follow(self.baseUrl+url, self.parse,dont_filter=True)
       
        
    def parse_icsstrive(self, response, **kwargs):
        title = ""
        published = ""
        type = ""
        summary = ""
        incident_Date = ""
        location = ""
        estimated_Cost = ""
        victims_url = ""
        victim_title = ""
        malwares_urls = ""
        threat_source_urls = ""
        references_name = ""
        references_url = ""
        industries = ""
        impacts = ""
        title=response.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/text()').get()
        published=response.xpath('//p[@class="et_pb_title_meta_container"]/span/text()').get()
        type=response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/text()').get()
        summary=response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/p/text()').get()
        incident_Date = response.xpath('//h3[text()="Incident Date"]/following-sibling::*//text()').get()
        location = response.xpath('//h3[text()="Location"]/following-sibling::p/a/text()').get()
        estimated_Cost = response.xpath('//h3[text()="Estimated Cost"]/following-sibling::p/text()').get()
        victims_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/h3[text()="Victims"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/a/@href').getall()
        malwares_urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/h3[text()="Type of Malware"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/a/@href').getall()
        threat_source_urls = response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/h3[text()="Threat Source"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/a/@href').getall()
        references_name = response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/h3[text()="References"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/a/text()').getall()
        references_url = response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/h3[text()="References"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/a/@href').getall()
        industries = response.xpath('//h3[text()="Industries"]/following-sibling::p/a/text()').get()
        impacts = response.xpath('//h3[text()="Impacts"]/following-sibling::*//text()').get()

        item = {
            "title": title,
            "published": published,
            "type": type,
            "summary": summary,
            "incident_Date": incident_Date,
            "estimated_Cost": estimated_Cost,
            "references": ",".join(references_name),
            "industries": industries,
        }
        if location is not None:
            item["location"]= location.replace("'", '"')
        if impacts is not None:
            item["impacts"]= impacts.replace("'", '"')
       
        # Extract malware URLs
        if len(victims_url) > 0: 
            for url in victims_url:
                request= scrapy.Request(url + "?dummy=" + str(random.random()),callback=self.parse_victims,dont_filter=True,meta={'item': item, 'malwares_urls': malwares_urls, 'threat_source_urls':threat_source_urls})
                request.meta['dont_cache'] = True
                yield request
        else:
            yield item
```

type here

```
 
    
    def parse_victims(self, response, **kwargs):
        victim_title = ""
        victim_published = ""
        victim_des = ""
        victim_title=response.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/text()').get()
        victim_des=response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/p/text()').get()
        victim_published = response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/h3[text()="Incidents"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/strong/text()').getall()
    
        item = response.meta['item']
       
        malwares_urls = response.meta['malwares_urls']
        threat_source_urls = response.meta['threat_source_urls']
        item["victim_title"] = victim_title
        item["victim_des"] = victim_des
        item["victim_url"] = response.url
        if victim_published:
            item["victim_published"] = victim_published[0]
        if item["title"]=="Chinese Identified Hackers Targeting Hawaii Water Utilities and unidentified Oil & Gas Pipeline in US":
             print(item)
       
        if len(malwares_urls) > 0:
            for malware_url in malwares_urls:
                request= scrapy.Request(malware_url+ "?dummy=" + str(random.random()), callback=self.parse_malware,dont_filter=True, meta={'item': item, 'threat_source_urls':threat_source_urls})
                request.meta['dont_cache'] = True
                yield request
        elif len(threat_source_urls) > 0:
            for threat_source_url in threat_source_urls:
                request= scrapy.Request(threat_source_url+ "?dummy=" + str(random.random()), callback=self.parse_threat_source,dont_filter=True,meta={'item': item})
                request.meta['dont_cache'] = True
                yield request
        else:
            yield item   
    def parse_malware(self, response, **kwargs):
        malware_title = ""
        malware_published = ""
        malware_des = ""
        malware_title=response.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/text()').get()
        malware_des=response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/p/text()').get()
        malware_published = response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/h3[text()="Incidents"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/strong/text()').getall()
        item = response.meta['item']
        threat_source_urls = response.meta['threat_source_urls']
        item["malware_title"] = malware_title
        item["malware_des"] = malware_des
        
        if malware_published:
            item["malware_published"] = malware_published[0]
        if len(threat_source_urls) > 0:
            for threat_source_url in threat_source_urls:
                request= scrapy.Request(threat_source_url+ "?dummy=" + str(random.random()), callback=self.parse_threat_source,dont_filter=True,meta={'item': item})
                request.meta['dont_cache'] = True
                yield request
        else:
            yield item   

    def parse_threat_source(self, response, **kwargs):
        threat_source_title = ""
        threat_source_published = ""
        threat_source_des = ""
        threat_source_title=response.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/text()').get()
        threat_source_des=response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/p/text()').get()
        threat_source_published = response.xpath('//div[@class="et_pb_text_inner"]/h3[text()="Incidents"]/following-sibling::div/ul/li/strong/text()').getall()
        item = response.meta['item']
        item["threat_source_title"] = threat_source_title
        item["threat_source_des"] = threat_source_des
        if item["title"]=="Chinese Identified Hackers Targeting Hawaii Water Utilities and unidentified Oil & Gas Pipeline in US":
             print(item)
        if threat_source_published:
            item["threat_source_published"] = threat_source_published[0]
        yield item
```

Comment: I used different techniques including disabling cache, using scrapy.Request, using response.follow_all but when create json file i saw victims repeat evrytime and threat source and malware is null

Comment: It is repeating because you are telling it to repeat in your parse method.

Comment: You are also adding dont_filter=True to all of your requests... don't do that.

Comment: you are also yielding the same object multiple times from multiple different parse methods.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple reasons in your code that are causing items to repeat themselves in the output.

##### Causes

1. You are using `dont_filter=True` in nearly all of your requests.  This disables scrapy's built in duplicate filter and leads to parsing the same page more than once.
2. In your `parse` method towards the end you are collecting all of the pagination links and then sending requests for each of them in a loop and sending them each to the parse method.  So everytime you parse any page it is making the same requests for every other page over again.
3. You `yield` a dictionary from nearly every parse method and then you pass that same dictionary to the next parse method in the request `meta` and `yield` it again which will cause both duplicates and incomplete items because you yield them before they are complete.

##### Possible Solutions

1. Remove the dont_filter parameters from your requests.
2. Instead of sending requests for each page each time the parse method is run, instead only submit the request for the next page.
3. Don't yield items that are incomplete, If you are going to send a dictionary through to a another parsing method then wait until the dictionary is complete to yield it to output.

Here is an example of 1 & 2:

```
import scrapy

class icsstriveSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "icsstrive"
    start_urls = ['https://icsstrive.com/']
    baseUrl="https://icsstrive.com"
    pages = None

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('div.search-r-title a::attr(href)').getall():
            yield response.follow(link, self.parse_icsstrive)
        current_page = response.css('li.wpv_page_current')
        if next_page := current_page.xpath("./following-sibling::li/a/@href").get():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page))

    def parse_icsstrive(self, response):
        victims_links = response.xpath("//div[h3[text()='Victims']]//li/a/@href").getall()
        victims = response.xpath("//div[h3[text()='Victims']]//li//text()").getall()
        malware_links = response.xpath("//div[h3[text()='Type of Malware']]//li/a/@href").getall()
        malware = response.xpath("//div[h3[text()='Type of Malware']]//li//text()").getall()
        threat_source_links = response.xpath("//div[h3[text()='Threat Source']]//li/a/@href").getall()
        threat_source = response.xpath("//div[h3[text()='Threat Source']]//li/a/text()").getall()
        title = response.xpath('//h1[@class="entry-title"]/text()').get()
        yield {
            "title": title,
            "victims": victims,
            "victims_links": victims_links,
            "malware": malware,
            "malware_links": malware_links,
            "threat_source_links": threat_source_links,
            "threat_source": threat_source
        }
```